# putting multiple php rows into database, keeps repeating last one, not unique

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Hi all so I have a php input form to record some racing results but let's say we have three different racers for the same racingeventID, but of course each will have different rank and time taken.

What my code seems to do is, if I enter the results of three of these racers, it just takes the last entry and repeats it three times rather than keeping them all unique. My explanation technique isn't that great but maybe someone could understand after seeing my code:

INPUT:

```
$reID = $_GET['reID'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM RaceEventRacer WHERE reID = $reID");

$count = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $count++;

    $reID = $row['reID'];
    $racerID = $row['racerID'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$reID<input type='hidden' name='reID$count' value='$reID'>"; 
    echo "<td>$racerID<input type='hidden' name='racerID$count' value='$racerID'>"; 

    echo"<td><input type='text' name='rank$count'>";
    echo"<td><input type='text' name='timetaken$count'>";   

}
echo "<input type='hidden' name='count' value='$count' />";
```

SQL INPUT:

```
$count = $_POST['count'];
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
    $rank[] = $_POST['rank'.$count];
    $timetaken[] = $_POST['timetaken'.$count];
    $reID[] = $_POST['reID'.$count];
    $racerID[] = $_POST['racerID'.$count];
}
$count_racerID = $count;

for($i=0;$i<$count_racerID;$i++){
    $_rank= mysql_escape_string($rank[$i]);
    $_timetaken= mysql_escape_string($timetaken[$i]);
    $_reID= mysql_escape_string($reID[$i]);
    $_racerID= mysql_escape_string($racerID[$i]);

    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO RaceResults (rank, timetaken, reID, racerID) VALUES ('$_rank', '$_timetaken', '$_reID', '$_racerID')");
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

So if I enter the results for three unique racers, it just takes the last result and enters that three times...

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo while populating your array. Also, the first ID index for your inputs starts at 1 since it's incremented before being used.
It should be:

```
for($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++){
    $rank[] = $_POST['rank'.$i];
    $timetaken[] = $_POST['timetaken'.$i];
    $reID[] = $_POST['reID'.$i];
    $racerID[] = $_POST['racerID'.$i];
}
```

Comment: just tried that, I get the error undefined index: rank/timetaken/reId/racerID

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the *$count++* statement should go at the end of the While loop. Otherwise, the count will start at 1, whereas the array in the backend would start at 0.

Another suggestion I have is to name your inputs using brackets to denote they are arrays. Instead of giving them manually unique names with the $count variable, just push to the same input

```
    echo "<td>$reID<input type='hidden' name='reID[]' value='$reID'>";
```

That means to update the backend code accordingly. A forEach loop would suffice.